# General solution to the wave equation in one dimension

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics

In physics I am studying the wave equation. We saw that we could use a separable ansatz of the form: $$ u(x,t)=f(x)g(t)$$ to try and solve it. By Rearranging the PDE we get an equation with turns out to be constant: 
$$ c^2\frac 1f \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=\frac 1g\frac{d^2g}{dt ^2}=-a^2 $$. We then get two equations that resemble the SHM equation. However, my teacher skipped the solution and wrote down that the solutions where: $$ f(x)=Ae^{\frac{iax}{c}}+Be^{\frac{-iax}{c}}, g(t)=Ce^{iat}+De^{-iat}$$ I have two questions: 1) how de we know that the constant term is $-a^2$, IE why the minus and the square?. 2) Why are the solutions not like the ones to the SHM equation: $$g(t)=C\cos(at)+ D\sin(at), f(x)=A\cos(ax/c) + B\sin(ax/c)$$
Any help would be great!

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve the readability of your question.

Comment: Hi, I am relatively knew to this website. How to I format using MathJax?

Comment: See: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are granted to find wave-like solutions only with a negative constant. The square of it is just to be sure it is positive and also for convenience in further calculations.
2. Indeed, they are. You have just to remember the Euler's identity $e^{i\phi}=\cos(\phi)+i\sin(\phi)$ and redefine the constants. To see this, let us consider $g(t)$. You will have
   $$
   g(t)=Ce^{iat}+De^{-iat}=C(\cos(at)+i\sin(at))+D(\cos(at)-i\sin(at)).
   $$
   Collecting identical terms one arrives to
   $$
   g(t)=(C+D)\cos(at)+i(C-D)\sin(at)
   $$
   and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for helping! For Q1 looks like you resolved my query. However, wouldn't expanding f(x) give $f(x)=Acos(ax/c)+iAsin(ax/c) + Bcos(ax/c)-iBsin(ax/c)$ ?

Comment: I expanded the answer to help you on point 2.

Comment: Hi, thanks again. My confusion is that the equation we get using ansatz is the SHM equation which has real solutions. The expression $Ae^{iat} + Be^{-iat} $ , however has an imaginary part, making a complex function.

Comment: You are correct. The consistency is obtained by assuming $C$ and $D$ complex numbers in such a way that $C+D$ and $i(C-D)$ are both real numbers.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying, my physics teacher did not go over this. What you are saying is that $ C+D \in \mathbb{R} $ and that $C-D \in \mathbb{C}, Re(C-D)=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, $C+D,\ i(C-D)\in\mathbb{R}$.